# How to organize my project?

Tags: objective-c, json, web-services

I would like to create a project but i don't really know how to organize it and what do i exactly need.

I want an application which has a tableview ( grouped  section ), with a refresh ( pull down ) of the framework three20, then when the user refresh the uitableview, the app check the webservice and ( i guess ) get the JSON and update the tableview ( by populate a plist ? )

so what do i need ?

a webservice, with a backfront where i can update my json ?
my application which has a plist populated by the json received from the webservice ?

AND

i have another view, where the user can send to the webservice information about him and update it when he wants. he will have in the application a page where he can see his information that he sent to the webservice earlier.

ps : should i use coredata ?

hope you get what i wanted.

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use coredata, i find it organizes everything much better, but there is of course an associated overhead with using it. You should definitely use it when you will be editing the information you have stored, sounds like per your requirement even though you do store the data, once you edit it you send it back to the web service, so you are not really modifying your stored data.

Therefore a p list would work just fine, but again there is nothing wrong with storing it in core data. Your general idea is correct, you will be calling your web service, parsing the JSON or XML that you get and refreshing your table with the data.

Depending on what communication protocol (SOAP, REST) and the response (JSON, XML) the Web service is using there are tools that will generate all you need for the communication, you don't really need to do all that by yourself.

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you please develop the last paragraph ("there are tools that will generate") ?

i wanted to use the HTTPS' class for the communication ( i'm wrong :p ? )

Comment: @user1256827 Well usually Web Services communicate using SOAP or REST, but there are some other methods, looks like you have something custom there, so you will have to communicate with it writing all the code yourself.